# How to stop a thread in Java immediately

Tags: java, multithreading, audio

I am creating a game which requires a lot of sounds to be played rapidly. Each sound is represented by a Sound class, the `play()` method of which creates a Thread object to modify the Clip asynchronously, because for some reason `clip.stop()` was causing a noticeable delay after a while. My problem is that after a while, all these threads build up, and eventually the program crashes with an OutOfMemoryError.

```
public void play()
{
    Thread thread = new Thread()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            if (clip.isRunning()) clip.stop();
            clip.setFramePosition(0);
            if (isAmbient) clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);
            else clip.start();
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);
                join();
            }
            catch (InterruptedException ie)
            {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    thread.setDaemon(true);
    thread.start();
}
```

I have tried to look for an answer to this question elsewhere, but the threads I am creating do not loop; they only need to execute once and then die immediately. If I don't use these threads, as I said before, playing the same sound in rapid succession becomes noticeably delayed after some time. I'm not so sure about this sound engine anyway, so any pointers to a pauseable and resumeable wav player would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Have you considered a [Thread Pool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You are using `join()` inside your thread which does not make any sense.  `Join` method returns when the thread is no longer alive. In your case as you are calling `join` method inside your alive thread, it would never return.